# Load image using AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have create a simple web site using angularjs and bootstrap.
In one page, I load a static image and I set some botton on this using bootbox.

When I run in local my site using

```
grunt serve
```

I see the image with the button on this.
When I try to run my site using

```
http-server -p 9000
```

I can't see the image, I see only the bottom.

This is my code that load image and button in the HTML page:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <img src="../maps/MappaWifi.jpg" alt="img_source" title="img_source" style='height: 100%; width: 100%; object-fit: contain'>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs Arduino1ZN" alt="Arduino1ZN" ng-click="mapsPageCtrl.Arduino1ZNCtrl()">Arduino1</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs Arduino2ZN" alt="Arduino2ZN" ng-click="mapsPageCtrl.Arduino2ZNCtrl()">Arduino2</button>

    </div>
</div>
```

I think that the problem is where I set the path.
Thanks all for help.

Comment: Where is your root folder located? Where is the maps folder located in relation to the root folder of your server?

Comment: My root folder is /home/jarvis/documents/server and my folder that contains the map is /home/jarvis/documents/server/app/iot/maps, map is in the folder of the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are pointing your folder to the wrong path. So, you can try setting your `src` like the below code and it should work fine. As you mentioned your maps folder is `/home/jarvis/documents/server/app/iot/maps` I'm suposing it's your root folder is `/home/jarvis/documents/server`, then in relation to your root the maps folder should look like:

```
<img src="iot/maps/MappaWifi.jpg" ...
```

Comment: Thanks, it return me the 404 error , image not found.

Comment: Where is the index.html file located?

Comment: It is in the folder /home/jarvis/documents/server/app

Comment: Can you try this path instead `iot/maps/MappaWifi.jpg`?

Comment: Which path? if i use /home/jarvis/documents/server/app, image is not load because it isnt define

Comment: This: <img src="iot/maps/MappaWifi.jpg" ..>. If you're running oyur index file from the app folder, then is should work relatively to the maps folder.